# HTTP Error 500.52 - URL Rewrite Module Error

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config, angular2-routing

URL routing is working fine but when i create application in IIS website, application stop working with error

> HTTP Error 500.52 - URL Rewrite Module

This rule is working fine (http://abcd/)

```
<rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="false">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />

          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/"/>
        </rule>
```

But when i change it application it gives error (http://abcd/app/)

```
<rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="false">
          <match url="(^app/.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />

          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/app/"/>
        </rule>
```

[image: Error Image]

> I have searched on google but found no solution. Expert guides is need.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your config error says:

> Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'rule' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'AngularJS Routes'

You'll probably need to change one of your `rule` name to make it work, for example:

```
<rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="false">[...]</rule>
<rule name="AngularJS App Routes" stopProcessing="false">[...]</rule>
```

Comment: this one help me alot, I had to rename the rule name, because, maybe there are more than 1 same rule name , (publish from Visual Studio)

Comment: Nope I still get the message even when I change my name